# How to get main menu only with wp_nav_menu

Tags: wp-query, menus, pages, navigation

I have created one menu and have some sub-menu but I don't want to display any sub-menu from my template.

My Menu code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'header-uk', 'menu_id' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => 'sitemap', 'fallback_cb' => false) ); ?>
```

My Menu Screenshot:

[image]

I want to display only this menu in my template:

```
Awards
Sagres Town
Getting Here
Sister Hotels
Other
Work for Martinhal
Disclaimer
Site Map
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the depth parameter like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'        => 'header-uk',
    'menu_id'     => 'nav',
    'menu_class'  => 'sitemap',
    'fallback_cb' => false,
    'depth'       => 1,
) );
```

Or if what you want to do is grab all items to create your own loop/output you can do that as well. Example:

```
if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ 'header-uk' ] ) ) {

    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ 'header-uk' ] );

    if ( ! empty( $menu ) ) {

        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );

            if ( $menu_items ) {

                foreach ( $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {

                    if ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {

                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $menu_item->url ) . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';

                    }

                }

            }

    }

}
```

The key is in the menu_item_parent check which makes sure an item isn't a child item before echoing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS trick, not related to WordPress I guess. BTW you can do something like this:

```
ul.sitemap{
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

ul.sitemap li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

As you've declared the `'menu_class' => 'sitemap'` the `<ul>` will get a class `.sitemap` that's why we are targeting that class to put our CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the [depth parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters) in the `wp_nav_menu` arguments

Comment: Could you please add the actual solution(code)? It really is easy in this case. Also have a look at [Provide context for links](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)